# Converting ActiveRecord array to JSON

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, json, active-record

I have two tables, `devices` and `device_properties`.

The `devices` table columns are as follows:

- `id`
- `ip`
- `mac`
- `device_property_id`
- `created_at`
- `updated_at`

The `device_properties` table columns are as follows:

- `id`
- `property_name`
- `cli_enabled`
- `created_at`
- `updated_at`

At the moment I have the following code to retrieve an array of devices as well as their properties:

```
@Data = Array.new
@Devices = Device.joins(:device_property)
@Devices.each do |d|
  p = d.device_property

  @Data.push({
    :device => {
      :id => d.id,
      :ip => d.ip,
      :mac => d.mac,
      :created_at => d.created_at,
      :updated_at => d.updated_at,
      :device_property_id => p.id,
      :property_name => p.property_name,
      :cli_enabled => p.cli_enabled
    }
  })
end
```

I return this as JSON:

```
render json: {
  "status" => "success",
  "data" => @Data
}
```

Is there a better way to render this all as JSON?

I was previously using this method:

```
@Data = Device.select("devices.*, device_properties.*").joins(:device_property)
```

But I soon discovered that the `id` that was being returned in the JSON was that of the `device_property` and not the `device`:

```
{
  "device" : {
    "id" : 13,
    "ip" : "192.168.1.2",
    "mac": "12:34:56:78:90:AB",
    "created_at" : "Oct 24th 2016",
    "updated_at" : "Oct 24th 2016",
    "device_property_id" : 13,
    "property_name" : "Disabled CLI",
    "cli_enabled" : false
  }
}
```

As you can see in the example, the `device.id` is matching `device_property.id`.

Comment: did you try to use serializer? something like [https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)